# Make all td the same size in table row

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have an HTML table row containing 5 columns. However for some reason the first  is wider than the others. Here is my code

```
<tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; font-size: 0.7em" width="200" colspan="5">
        + SOME STRINGYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY + 
    </td> <br/>
    <td style="border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0.7em" width="200" colspan="5">
        + SOME STRINGYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY + 
    </td> <br/>
    <td style="border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0.7em" width="200" colspan="5"> 
        + SOME STRINGYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY + 
    </td> <br/>
    <td style="border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0.7em" width="200" colspan="5">
        + SOME STRINGYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY + 
    </td> <br/>
    <td style="border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-left: none; font-size: 0.7em" width="200" colspan="5">
        + SOME STRINGYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY + 
    </td> <br/>
</tr>
```

I am trying to use it in outlook and it looks like this

[image]

Comment: I see it is working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/we1apd8s/7/

Comment: @Manjuboyz you right, actually my issue it that I have this <tr> within table that has other properties causing this specifically a <th> which has a no-wrap css.

your comment points me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: Not related to your initial question but it does not make sense to add `<br>` tags after `<td>`s and also why would you use `<td colspan="5">` on each element? This would in total span 25 columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
td{
 width: 20%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have given the td width same then it must be in the same size and there is no point in giving the colspan="5" and the above code is working fine in my machine. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iLDJ.png)